Unleash stickiness when scaling down, not up
Unleash allows that when scaling up a feature in a gradual rollout, the same users or entities will keep the same experience.
https://docs.getunleash.io/reference/stickiness
E.g., if you're in the first 10% who received the feature, you'll also still have the feature enabled when the rollout is increased to 20%.
(1) Does stickiness apply in the reverse direction?
I.e., if you received the feature after it rolled out to 100%, you'll continue to receive the feature even after the percentage decreases all the way to 0%, which will only apply to new user IDs or entity IDs not yet seen by Unleash.
(2) If the answer to the above is no, then is there an option to get this functionality?
(Have not tried this; I believe the answer to my first question is no but even if I proved that to be the case, it would still leave my second question open)

(1) No, per the docs you linked, if you're using a user ID for stickiness it will always hash to the same value, so if you decrease the % rollout such that a given user's number is now outside the threshold, they won't receive it anymore.

Unleash calculates stickiness based on the user id and the group id. If the user id is unavailable, it falls back to using the session id instead. It hashes these values to a number between 0 and 100 using the MurmurHash hash function. This number is what determines whether a user will see a specific feature or variant. Because the process is deterministic, the same user will always get the same number.


...When using the gradual rollout activation strategy, any user whose number is less than or equal to the rollout percentage will see the feature. This means that the same users will keep seeing the feature even as you increase the percentage of your user base that sees the feature.

(2) It's probably possible to implement a "one-way valve" of stickiness with a Custom Stickiness parameter, but at that point you're tracking who should get the feature outside of Unleash, which may defeat the purpose of using it.
